# Results Random Forest Regression Optimization

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm going to optimize the hyperparameters of a Random Forest Regressor using scikit-learn and GridSearchCV, with the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [30,40,50,60,79],
    'min_samples_leaf': [5,10,15,20],
    'min_samples_split': [10,12,14,16,20],
    'n_estimators': [80,100,110,120]
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 10, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
    mape = 100 * np.mean(errors / test_labels)
    accuracy = 100 - mape
    print('Model Performance')
    print('Average Error: {:0.4f} degrees.'.format(np.mean(errors)))
    print('Accuracy = {:0.2f}%.'.format(accuracy))
    
    return accuracy
    
print (grid_search.best_params_)

best_grid = grid_search.best_estimator_
grid_accuracy = evaluate(best_grid, X_test, y_test)
print (grid_accuracy)
```

The performances after the optimization decrease in terms of RMSE. Basically, just using the standard library call the RMSE is lower than the RMSE with hyperparameters optimization. is it possible?

Comment: You have not specified the metric to optimize for in GridSearchCV

Comment: Try hyperparameters 'n_estimators': [1, 10, 100] and 'n_samples_split': 1/numpy.logspace(1, 4, 10, dtype=float)

Comment: Minor thin, but MAPE is not same as RMSE

Comment: Is this a classification or regression problem? What are your labels?

Comment: @jonnor this is a regression problem. and the target labels are numerical variable